# Properties of independence and conditional independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Recently, I see some properties from conditional independence wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence

I don't quite understand the properties of "**Rules of conditional independence**" in the wiki page.

Definition: $X\perp A$ means random variables $A$ and $X$ are independent from each other. $X\perp A\ |\ B$ means random variables $A$ and $X$ are conditionally independent given random variable $B$.

*Question 1*: how to prove "**Contraction-weak-union-decomposition**" property as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{array}{rl}
X\perp A\ |\ B\\
X\perp B
\end{array}
\right\}
and\ \ \ \ \ \ \Leftrightarrow
\ \ \ \ \ \ X\perp A,B
\ \ \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow
\ \ \ \ \ \ and\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
X\perp A\ |\ B\\
X\perp B\\
X\perp B\ |\ A\\
X\perp A
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}

*Question 2*: how to prove the "**Intersection**" rule as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{array}{rl}
X\perp A\ |\ B\\
X\perp B\ |\ A
\end{array}
\right\}
and\ \ \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow
\ \ \ \ \ \ X\perp A,B
\end{equation*}

*Question 3*: Is the inverse proposition of "**Decomposition**" rule still true? how to comprehend it, please give me an example.

**Original proposition:**
\begin{equation*}
X\perp A,B\ \ \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow
\ \ \ \ \ \ and
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
X\perp A\\
X\perp B
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
**Inverse proposition:**
\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{array}{rl}
X\perp A\\
X\perp B
\end{array}
\right\}
and\ \ \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow
\ \ \ \ \ \ X\perp A,B
\end{equation*}
Thanks very much!

Comment: Please make your question self-contained, one should not have to visit an offsite page to understand it.

Comment: These are direct consequences of the definitions, for example $X\perp A\mid B$ and $X\perp B$ means that $P(X=x,A=a\mid B=b)=P(X=x\mid B=b)P(A=a\mid B=b)$ and that $P(X=x,B=b)=P(X=x)P(B=b)$ for every $(x,a,b)$, hence...

Comment: I understand how to prove *Question 1*, but what about *Question 2* and *Question 3*

Comment: Please show your solution to 1 and your tries to 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proof of *Question 1*:

first arrow, left to right:
\begin{eqnarray}
P(X, A, B) & = & P(X, A\ |\ B)P(B)\\
& = & P(X\ |\ B)P(A\ |\ B)P(B)\ \ \ \ \ because\ X\ and\ A\ are\ conditionally\ independent\ on\ B\\
& = & P(X\ |\ B)P(AB)\\
& = & P(X)P(AB)\ \ \ \ \ because\ X\ and\ B\ are\ independent
\end{eqnarray}
first arrow, right to left:
\begin{eqnarray}
P(X, A, B) & = & P(X)P(A,B)\ \ \ \ \ because\ X\ and\ A,B\ are\ indepentdent\\
\int_BP(X, A, B) & = & \int_BP(X)P(A,B)\\
P(X,A) & = & P(X)P(A)
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, $X\perp A$, similarly $X\perp B$.
\begin{eqnarray}
P(X, A\ |\ B) & = & \frac{P(X,A,B)}{P(B)}\\
&=&\frac{P(X)P(AB)}{P(B)}\ \ \ \ \ because\ X\ and\ A,B\ are\ indepentdent\\
&=&P(X)P(A\ |\ B)\\
&=&P(X\ |\ B)P(A\ |\ B)\ \ \ \ \ because\ X\ and\ B\ are\ indepentdent
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, $X\perp A\ |\ B$

second arrow: we can obtain that from the first arraw.

Comment: It seems that a similar approach would solve Q2, wouldn't it? Re Q3, you may want to look for a counterexample.

Comment: I just can't prove Q2. For Q3, yes, I want to look for a counterexample.

Comment: Re Q2, you should be able to reach the identity $$P(X=x\mid A=a,B=b)=P(X=x\mid A=a)=P(X=x\mid B=b)$$ for every $(x,a,b)$. Hence, $$P(X=x)=\sum_aP(A=a)P(X=x\mid A=a)=\sum_aP(A=a)P(X=x\mid B=b)=P(X=x\mid B=b).$$ By symmetry, $P(X=x)=P(X=x\mid A=a)$, QED.

Comment: Sorry, I think what you prove is about Q2.
You prove that \begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{array}{rl}
X\perp A\ |\ B\\
X\perp B\ |\ A
\end{array}
\right\}
and\ \ \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow
\ \ \ \ \ \ (X\perp A)\ and\ (X\perp B)
\end{equation*} not $X\perp A,B$

Comment: "Sorry, I think what you prove is about Q2." ?? Yes, which is why the comment starts by "Re Q2". "You prove that ... not X⊥A,B" ?? One gets P(X=x∣A=a,B=b)=P(X=x∣A=a)=P(X=x∣B=b)=P(X=x). If this is not "X⊥A,B", then what is?

Comment: I got it! It's great a proof. Have you any idea on Q3? Can I say $X\perp A,B$ is stronger than $(X\perp A) and (X\perp B)$? Could you please give  a counterexample?Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... Let me advise you to look for simple examples.

Comment: OK, I have thought for a long time and can't find some examples. Could you please find me some?

Comment: Let $A=B$, then trivially $X \perp A \mid A$, but it doesn't follow that $X \perp A$.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer and comments give proofs for Q1 and Q2. For Q3, the answer is no:

Let A, B be two independent Bernoulli random variables $\mathcal{B}(\frac{1}{2})$ (e.g. representing unbiased coin flips), and let $X = A \oplus B$ (i.e. $X = 1$ whenever $A \neq B$, $X=0$ otherwise).

Then for $x, a \in \{0,1\}$:
$P(X=x, A=a) = P(B=|x-a|, A=a) = 1/2 \cdot 1/2 = P(X=x) \cdot P(A=a)$.

Therefore, $X⊥A$. Similarly, $X⊥B$, but since $X$ is entirely known if we know $A$ and $B$, we do not have $X⊥A,B$.